# How to center an unorganized list within a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

So i'm currently working on building my own website but ran into some trouble when it came to centering my actual ul within my navigation bar. The nav bar is already centered and fine but i am trying to center the actual ul and still keep it left aligned. I am using Brackets text editor. Any Help ?

Thanks in advance and heres my CSS code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 100 0;
}

.mainimg {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10 auto;
}

.mainimg img {}

.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.nav-bar li {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.nav-bar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Satori</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="imageslider">
    <img src="images/SATORI%20ARROW%20LEFT.png" width=100px alt="left">
    <img class="mainimg" src="images/satori-for-web-background.png" alt="oauihgoiw">
    <img src="images/SATORI%20ARROW%20RIGHT.png" width=100px alt="right">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Station</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Films</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Art</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Podcast</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Music</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that is because of float:left on li. make them display:inline-block

Comment: Okay will try it out now

Comment: Remove li `width` and `float:left` use `display:inline-block` or  `display:inline-flex`

Answer (score 0):

Update below css part

```
.nav-bar li {
 display:inline-flex; /* OR display:inline-block */
 /* float:left; */
/* width: 10%; */
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 100 0;
}

.mainimg {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10 auto;
}

.mainimg img {}

.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.nav-bar li {
 display:inline-flex; /* OR display:inline-block */
 /* float:left; */
/* width: 10%; */
}

.nav-bar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageslider">
    <img src="images/SATORI%20ARROW%20LEFT.png" width=100px alt="left">
    <img class="mainimg" src="images/satori-for-web-background.png" alt="oauihgoiw">
    <img src="images/SATORI%20ARROW%20RIGHT.png" width=100px alt="right">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Station</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Films</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Art</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Podcast</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Music</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```